# Non-string literals are prvalues?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, lvalue, user-defined-literals

I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but, user-defined literals, which invokes user-defined functions that could return anything, are also a kind of literals.

The standard says that a literal is always a prvalue, unless it is a string literal, [but](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/226d76a618817823):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int& operator""_a(unsigned long long c);

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(5_a), int&>::value;
}
```

prints 1 in both GCC and Clang, which proofs that the literal `5_a` (which is not a string literal) is being treated as a lvalue instead of an rvalue:

> [**[expr.prim.literal]/1**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr#prim.literal-1) A *literal* is a primary expression. Its type depends on its form. A string literal is an lvalue; all other literals are prvalues.

and user-defined literals are **[literals too](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.literal.kinds#1)**.

What is what I'm missing?

Comment: According to [this value category reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) lvalues include "a function call or an overloaded operator expression, whose return type is lvalue reference". What user-defined literals really are, are overloaded operators (in the case of your example, `5_a` is equal to the call `operator""_a(5)`). And your operator function returns an lvalue reference, which you compare to an lvalue reference of the same type.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but it is also a literal. It is, besides, written in *italics*, to emphatice that it refers to all the constructors under the *literal* syntax rule, and I would say a standard cannot contain contradictions.

Comment: @Peregring-lk A standard is a document written by humans. What do you mean it cannot contain contradictions? It *should* not, using standards definitions it *must* not, but it probably does anyway and this may be one of them.

Comment: @DanielH Yes of course. I don't meant I'm demanding it must be correct, but to express that the solution must be either it is a defect of the standard or a defect in my reading, because a standard wants to be a "contradictory"-free document. Maybe in my mother language "cannot" is less restrictive in informal speech than in english.

Comment: Not putting this as an answer as I'm not 100% sure but I think [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.literal#7) is the reason why you are not seeing it is a prvalue.

Comment: @NathanOliver I already read that but it's a note (non-normative), and it says that is constrained by the previous bullets (whose, by context, makes it a literal), and thus [expr.prim.literal]/1 still applies.

Comment: The note may not be normative. But it leads to [lex.ext]/[2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.ext#2). And that *is* normative

Comment: Obvious standard wording defect is obvious. Does this actually matter? Yes, `5_a` is an lvalue in your example, and presumably all compilers correctly invoke it as such. Is there a real source of confusion?

Comment: @Barry No, but you cannot then theoretically resort on user-defined literals returning references of any kind.

Comment: @Peregring-lk Who can't? Your question states that gcc and clang both interpret that expression as an lvalue.

Comment: @Barry can I deduce by your words that the correct reading of the standard is the common output between Clang and GCC instead of the standard itself?

Comment: @Barry I know that this specific question is not a very important one, but moving the solution to compiler outputs I think is not a way of addressing contradictions, even if they are not polemic. I knew beforehand that the output should be an lvalue; I just ask the question because reading that made me to not be sure, because sometimes things that seems obvious aren't, like that `using T = decltype([]{}); T t;` is ill-formed while `template<class T> void f(T const&) { T t; t(); }; f([]{});` isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a minor wording defect in the standard. You can find that sentence (nearly) unchanged all the way back in [N1905](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf):

> A *literal* is a primary expression. Its type depends on its form (2.13). A string literal is an lvalue; all other literals are rvalues.

This standard predates user-defined literals by a few years ([N2765](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2765.pdf) is from mid-2008), and this particular wording wasn't change to reflect that the "all other literals are [p]rvalues" part shouldn't include user-defined literals.

However, it's pretty clear that since a user-defined-literal is simply syntax sugar for a [function call](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.literal#lex.ext-2.sentence-1), its value category should be derived from the function call as well. That's the point of the language feature. There's no confusion that the value category of `5_a` in your example is lvalue and not prvalue (all compilers agree), so a defect report for this wording would get pretty low precedence, if any.